# Where to put label message and only display it after a process is done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, label

I am a beginner. How and where should i put a label messages after a video is created from below code.
 
I want to display two messages after the process is completed which is label1: video was created successfully and 2nd messages is videopath of the video.

I only want to display it after the process is completed(video was created).

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class liveRecording : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    //video codec
    AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("MSVC");  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string streamingSource = "http://xxx.sample.com:85/snapshot.cgi";
        string login = "login";
        string password = "password";

        JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);
        JPEGSource.Login = login;
        JPEGSource.Password = password;
        JPEGSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        JPEGSource.Start();
    }

    public bool IsRecording = false;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    Queue<Bitmap> frames = new Queue<Bitmap>(); //Queue that store frames to be written by the recorder thread

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) //event handler for NewFrame
    {
        //get frame from JPEGStream source
        //Bitmap image = eventArgs.Frame;
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); //get a copy of the Bitmap from the source

        width = image.Width;
        height = image.Height;

        if (IsRecording)
        {
            //enqueue the current frame to be encoded to a video file
            frames.Enqueue((Bitmap)image.Clone());
        }

        if (!IsRecording)
        {
            IsRecording = true;
            Thread th = new Thread(DoRecording);
            th.Start();
        }
    }

    private void DoRecording()
    {
        //writer.FrameRate = 5;
        string SavingPath = (Server.MapPath("~\\video\\")); 
        string VideoName = "ICS_" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".avi";
        writer.Open(SavingPath + VideoName, width, height);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Seconds < 30)
        {
            if (frames.Count > 0)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = frames.Dequeue();
                writer.AddFrame(bmp);//add frames to AVI file
            }
        }
        writer.Close();//close
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only want to display it after the process is completed(video was created).

Then you should use AJAX, basically. Your "start encoding" (or whatever) request should complete *quickly*, so the user gets an appropriate page back. That page should contain Javascript to regularly poll the server to see whether the task has completed - you'll need some coordination (e.g. via a randomly generated "job ID" which is provided to the client). You could use something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for "long polling" (where the AJAX fires a request which is expected to wait until either the job has completed or it times out) or just make a quick polling request every few seconds.

I'm afraid none of this is *easy* if you're new to web development - but the task you're trying to perform isn't easy, in a world based on HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: It requires always pinging to server to check status of video. You can try to put AJAX Progress bar to see the progress of the video. And can show the message when progress bar stops.

Comment: @Jon Skeet 1hour searching/reading from internet but still not able to understand. can i just use this `this.Label1.Text = "Message";`?

Comment: @Rajaram Shelar could you explain it more? i mean can u provide me a code on how to do that or maybe a link?

Comment: @Lynx: No - you need to understand that the original page request should be *fast*. It can start a long-running task, but then it should return a response to the browser.

Comment: from Rajaram suggestion, i added AJAX progress bar and display the message after progress bar stop. The code ran fine but the progress bar stop based on thread running time(`Thread.Sleep(2000);`). The question is how can i stop the progress bar based on the real process in the code behind(`DoRecording()`) completed? Mean that the progress bar stopped because of the `doRecording()` process is completed not because of the thread time is expired.

Comment: @Lynx: I'm afraid at this point it's very hard to follow what you're really doing - and I don't want to just keep repeating myself. You mustn't do the long-running task in the original page fetch. You've got to give something back to the client, so they can poll.

Comment: @Jon Skeet i am sory if i dont understand(new learner) but i just wanna see or testing how the code work. Its not a long-running task, i can adjust the `DoRecording()` to run only for 3seconds. So what i'm asking  is how can i check if the process is completed or not, so i can show a message to client telling that the task is completed.

Comment: @Lynx: If it requires a check for whether it's completed or not, then it's long-running. I'm afraid I've given as good an explanation as I can in the answer... just saying it again isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks Jon. i can see the road is still far and long for me as i cant even understand your good explanation but that how we start, a Questions for what we dont understand.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Found another problem with the code. It seem that the code or the thread(i think) is not properly closed. The **WebDev.WebServer40.EXE** still running and using all the memory of my computer. I can see the memory usage from task manager increasing even after i stopped the Visual Studio(stop debugging). Need to end task using task manager to stop. The code is executed whenever the page loaded, it suppose to terminate/close all the operation whenever the task completed but its not. How to solve the problem?? What should i add/remove??

Comment: @Lynx: This sounds like an entirely different issue, and one to ask in a different question. How you get feedback to a client is very separate from how you control the process.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: yeah, its different issue with the same code. Maybe i need to start a new thread for this question. But before that how can i solve this problem in my code?

Comment: @Lynx: I no longer have any idea what you mean by "this problem". If you mean the *new* problem, I'm not going to start answering a different question in comments. *Ask a new question.*

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, i will ask a new question for this new problem of mine.